# Local notifications not working how to fix it

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, emulation

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Patient Name"
    android:id="@+id/nameET"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Age"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/ageET" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerId" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Save"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Show notifications"
    android:id="@+id/btn" />
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
EditText nameET,ageET;
Spinner spinner;
Button login;
Button btn;
String[] genderArray = {"Male","Female"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameET = findViewById(R.id.nameET);
    ageET = findViewById(R.id.ageET);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerId);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,genderArray);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            makeNotification();
        }
    });
}
public void makeNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setContentTitle("Hi")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Collect your daily coins");

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

}
This is MainActivity.java 
I have used this code for local notifications without firebase when i click show notification button.It doesn't working what is problem and how to solve.I cannot found any error but output is not working anyone can solve my problem please see and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine.

Most probably,You are using this code on device version Oreo or above.

You are missing the part where you have to use notification channels on Versions Oreo and above.

Below is your code converted into a code snippet that will work on all Versions.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "Notification Channel";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;


    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createNotificationChannel();
                makeNotification();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);

            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

    }

    public void makeNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Hi")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("Collect your daily coins");

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityOne.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setGroup(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Consult this link for details about Notification Channels.
https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c